# Loading 8MP photos in the background on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm customizing a gallery similar to the Photos app in iOS. I want to be able to scroll between individual photos in my custom gallery. I am also preloading images that are likely to be shown soon (if I scroll to the right, I preload i.e. the 2 next images to the right)

However, the image loading seems to be so CPU consuming that it interferes with the scrolling. Making the scrolling hang for split of a second.

Is there any better way to do this? (I have considered keeping smaller versions of each image that matches the screen resolution)

Basically I call this in the background thread:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

and then I perform a selector on the main thread that just initialises an existing ImageView with the loaded image.

Comment: I notice slight hitches in my UI when loading large images using `imageWithContentsOfFile` in the foreground queue, and by moving that to the background queue, it makes scrolling silky smooth. If you're seeing hitches in your scrolling, then there's something else going on (did you accidentally dispatch synchronously?). You have to share more code, perhaps the whole "dispatch `imageWithContentsOfFile` to background queue and then dispatch the UI update back to the main queue" routine.

Comment: Yes, it was not synchronously. I solved my problem (answer below). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in a way.

I needed to render the image off-screen on the background thread to make sure it was loaded. Otherwise it would not actually load until I decided to render it in the main thread. This caused the main thread to block while loading.